# How do you to detect the end of a thread via ThreadId?

Tags: java, servlets

Talking Java Servlets here... I'm working on creating my own "Per Request Context" and I was looking to tie the "Per Request Context" object to the Thread.currentThread().getId() value.

Instead of passing around this context object everywhere I was planning on checking the current threadid when a user calls a function that is Per Request based and automatically getting the Context object out of a hashtable for that threadId.

I would use the code this like..

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ServletException, IOException
{
    MyFramework.EnterContext();
    try {
        // do stuff here that leads to other classes on the same thread
        // Access current context via static MyFramework.getCurrentContext()
    }
    finally { MyFramework.ExitContext(); }
}
```

However I would like to protect my application automatically from any potential user that does not call ExitContext(). <strike>In C# there is an event handler on the thread object for onexit...</strike>(think I wrong on this) is there some way to detect or poll when a thread exits? I'm currently storing only the threadId (long).

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you're off base here. For one, I think what you're doing with threads is wrong. You should be working within the servlet context.

Comment: ServletContext is for all users using the system. HttpSession is for the current user. What I need is a "Per Request" context, in other words multiple requests by the same user... I'm trying to avoid that situtation where my framework can be used in multiple spots on a page and loaded async, I dont want them executing at the same time because the info used would be per request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunatelly, there is no such feature built in for threads in Java. Besides, thread id is only guaranteed to be unique at any one time, but may be reused eventually when the thread dies (from the docs). however, the servlet framework that you are using may be implementing such feature (just a speculation).

i would recommend you implement a servlet filter, and tell your users to include it in their `web.xml`. with this you can be sure the client code always gets correctly wraped in your thread context.

Comment: Instead of that additional config I would rather just tell them they should be doing a try{}finally{} if they had problems. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I flipped flopped on this answer after more research with the ThreadLocal idea it turned out that Weblogic is using a ThreadPool to execute the threads so the thread's never really die. When weblogic (and tomcat apparently) put the thread back into the pool they dont clean off the ThreadLocal variables. Only after an application is redeployed does it clean them. In the end it turns out the only secure way to do it is to make a servlet filter. (FYI)Servlets 3.0 allows you to auto register them so no web.xml needed.

Comment: I see, that makes sense! Didn't know about the auto-registering, sounds useful!

Answer (score 1):

A [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) seems to fit your use perfectly. A ThreadLocal object can provide a way to store a variable per thread. The internal workings of this class are very much of what you describe, it uses a map to give thread-local variables.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<UserContext> userContext = new ThreadLocal<UserContext>();

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
              throws ServletException, IOException {
    MyFramework.EnterContext();
    try {
       UserContext context = userContext.get();
       //if you used the set method in this thread earlier
       //a thread local context would be returned using get
    }
    finally { MyFramework.ExitContext(); }
}
```

As for your other problem, you can use an observer pattern and notify when the thread completes its task.

Comment: FYI the thread is created by Tomcat, not me so the task is doPost(), it would make sense for the user to do the try-finally like I mentioned... But I really think what you mentioned here will work. One question though, it appears I don't need to observe with this method because this is actually attached to the thread, so when the thread goes away it should automatically put it up for collection. In your example this would hold true correct? Or would I need to set userContext to null at some point?

Comment: I found information specifically for tomcat saying if the ThreadLocal is not disposed of then newer versions of tomcat >=6.0.24 will warn about closing it, which is good enough for me. >= 7.0.6 will actually fix it automatically. So using this solution and also instructing to use try-finally should work out well.

Comment: See comment on answer why I flipped the answer over to rodion. I still am using the ThreadLocal, but it doesnt auto clean.